# Notation: Vector with two subscripts

Tags: notation, vectors

Suppose I have a vector with four elements:

$\mathbf{X} = [v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4]$

Now I want to add a time component to denote 12 separate vectors for each month in a single year.

For example:

$\mathbf{X_t} = [v_{1t}, v_{2t}, v_{3t}, v_{4t}]$

But I know this is not correct but not sure how to correct the notation.

What is an appropriate way to accomplish this notation?

Here is a simple matrix algebra example:

**Edit:**

Matrix Algebra example:

I'm trying to clean up this notation so it includes a time component.

$\mathbf{SP_{t}} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathcal{A}_{11} & \mathcal{A}_{12} & \mathcal{A}_{13} & \mathcal{A}_{14} \\ \mathcal{A}_{21} & \mathcal{A}_{22} & \mathcal{A}_{23} & \mathcal{A}_{24} \\ \mathcal{A}_{31} & \mathcal{A}_{32} & \mathcal{A}_{33} & \mathcal{A}_{34} \\ \mathcal{A}_{41} & \mathcal{A}_{42} & \mathcal{A}_{43} & \mathcal{A}_{44}  \end{bmatrix}$

$\mathbf{X_t} = [v_{1t}, v_{2t}, v_{3t}, v_{4t}]$

$\mathbf{Y_t} = \mathbf{X_t} \cdot \mathbf{SP_t} $

$\mathbf{Y_1} = \mathbf{X_1} \cdot \mathbf{SP_1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding a subscript to the left hand side as well, $$\mathbf{X}_t = [v_{1t}, v_{2t}, v_{3t}, v_{4t}]$$

To indicate that $SP_t$ indeed depends on time. Perhaps replace $\mathcal{A}_{ij}$ with $\mathcal{A}_{ijt}$.

Comment: Thanks. I should say that the elements vary with time as well. Is it appropriate to write $\mathbf{X_{it}} = [v_{1t}, v_{2t}, v_{3t}, v_{4t}]$

Comment: since you include $i$ on the left, perhaps $i$ should appear on the right as well?

Comment: Thanks, but a vector is one-dimensional, so is it appropriate to add a second dimension, $t$?

Comment: I don't have a full picture of what you are trying to achieve, what do you mean by the element vary with time? which element?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've added an example of what the notation I'm trying to clean up.

Comment: I don't see the issue with $X_t$ and don't see the need for $i$. I am curious if $SP$ should be time dependent because $A_{ij}$ seems to be independent of time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83210/discussion-between-amstell-and-siong-thye-goh).